# React spring use units with values

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I am using `react-spring` library to animate `width` of a component. How can I use different units such as `vw`, `%` with the animated values?

```
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";

export default function App() {
const animatedProps = useSpring({
    from: { width: 0 },
    to: { width: 100 },
    duration: "12s",
});

return (
    <animated.h1
    style={{
        ...animatedProps,
        width: animatedProps + "vw",
        bacgroundColor: "red",
    }}
    >
    <div>Hello CodeSandbox</div>
    </animated.h1>
);
}
```

But it wouldn't work. How can I use units?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `from: {width: "0vw"}, to: {width: "100vw"}`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't accept string values. It says `"Cannot animate between AnimatedValue and AnimatedString, as the "to" prop suggests"`

Comment: It should work. Please make sure you use same units in the “from.width” and “to.width” properties.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

You can include units when you use a callback.

Assigning the `width` from the variable directly like `animatedProps.width.to(value=>value + "vw")`

```
    <animated.h1
    style={{
        width: animatedProps.width.to(value=>value + "vw"),
        bacgroundColor: "red",
    }}
    >
    <div>Hello CodeSandbox</div>
    </animated.h1>
```